# How to set isSignedIn to true before Guard runs?

Tags: typescript, angular, router, rxjs5, ngrx

I am using **ngrx/router**.

I have a `LoginGuard`, when I open a page which needs to login, the LoginGuard runs before `isSignedIn` is set to true. So at that time `isSignedIn` is `undefined`.

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginGuard implements Guard {
  constructor(private _router: Router, private _userService: UserService) { }

  protectRoute({ route, params, isTerminal }: TraversalCandidate): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._userService.checkSignedIn()
      .map(isSignedIn => {
        if (!isSignedIn) {
          this._router.replace('/landing');
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }).first();
  }
}
```

I set `isSignedIn` to `true` in the beginning of the app, which is the earliest place in my mind.

```
class App implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    // I set isSignedIn in UserService to true here after I got user info from the server
  }
}
```

But maybe it is not early enough? So how can I set `isSignedIn` to `true` before **Guard** runs? Thanks

Comment: Can you post the checkSignedIn code?

Comment: @rtytgat thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My app actually uses a service checking access in an async way.

@rtytgat gives a solution. And thanks!

> Check with the Guard, if not logged in send them to 'logging in' page,
>   and send them back when login has been confirmed.